# Не срабатывает window.history.back()

Tags: google-chrome, javascript, history-api

Доброго дня всем.
Интересует вопрос, почему в браузере `Chome` не срабатывает функция `JScript'a` `window.history.back()`?
Или для Хрома костыль какой нужен к этой функции?

Comment: А вы уверены что функция не срабатывает ? как используете, что наблюдаете в итоге ?

Comment: Проверьте консоль. Позможно, вы опечатались в имени функции. В Chrome window.history.back() отлично работает. А может, в истории просто нет предыдущих адресов.

Comment: Только что проверил window.history.back() в консоли Хрома. Всё работает.

Comment: Вот такой у меня обработчик события:
> <script language="javascript">
> 
> function goBack()
> 
> {
> 
> window.history.back()
> 
> }
> 
> </script>
> 
> 
> ...<tr>
> 
> <td colspan="2" align="center">
> 
> <a href="" onclick="goBack()" style=" text-decoration:none; color:#ffcc00; 
font:bold 14px '';">&#60&#60 НАЗАД</a>
> 
> </td>
> 
> </tr>...

Вроде всё правильно, но и на локалке и на хостинге не работает.
(сейчас попробую с ноутбука...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте следующую директиву:

```
<script>
 function goBack() {
     history.go(-1);
 }
</script>
```

и

```
<a href="javascript:goBack()">Back</a>
```

Comment: не помогло...

Comment: Chrome Version 24.0.1312.57 m

Работает как часы:

a.html

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 </head>

 <body>
  <a href="b.html">go</a>
 </body>
</html>

b.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
 function goback() {
     history.go(-1);
 }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:goback()">Back</a>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Разница в HTML

В вашем примере через событие:

    <a href="" onclick="goBack()" style=" text-decoration:none; color:#ffcc00; font:bold 14px '';">&#60&#60 НАЗАД</a>

В моем передается через href:

    <a href="javascript:goBack()">Back</a>

Comment: Спасибо! ЗАРАБОТАЛО! Сразу просто не заметил, что через href

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать <button onclick='history.back();'>Назад</button>.

Comment: Так сработало!  
НО Ещё больше запутало!  
Почему на кнопке работает, а на ссылке нет (в Chrome)?  
так НЕТ - <a href="" onclick="goBack()" style="text-decoration:none; color:#ffcc00; font:bold 14px '';">&#60&#60 НАЗАД</a>  
а так ДА - <button onclick="goBack();">Назад</button>

Comment: Потому что после нажатия на ссылку происходит переход по этой ссылке.
Можно сделать так: <a href="" onclick="goBack(); return false;" style="text-decoration:none; color:#ffcc00; font:bold 14px '';">&#60&#60 НАЗАД</a>

Answer (score 0):

[History.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/)